Image Edit not workign after upgrade Magento2 with cropper js
In Old website Image edit function working fine, after upgrade of magento2 we are getting error in js console
Uncaught ReferenceError: imageEditor is not defined
Can anyone have idea about this issue.
Screen shot
I have tried compare it to old version Magento and found same count of the 'imageEditor'.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
